# Small generators of the ideal class group

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

If $K$ is a number field, a result from Bach tells us that the primes in $K$ of norm smaller that $12 (\log |\mathrm{Discriminant}(K)|)^2$ generate the ideal class group $\mathrm{Cl}_K$. Is there any known bound if we require the generating primes to be unramified in $K/\mathbb Q$? (i.e. a result of the form "prime ideals in $K$ above the prime numbers unramified in $K/\mathbb Q$ and smaller than $f(K)$ generate the ideal class group")

In the particular case I study, $[K:\mathbb Q] = 4$. With algebraic methods I can find a bound polynomial in the class number $h_K$ and logarithmic in $|\mathrm{Discriminant}(K)|$, but I am sure we can get rid of the $h_K$, or at least change it for a $\log h_K$, but I'm afraid this would require analytic methods...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, do not forget that Bach's result is conditional to GRH.

What Bach proves is that for every nontrivial character $\chi$ of the ray class group of $K$ of conductor $\mathfrak{f}$, there is a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of norm less or equal to $3\log(\Delta_K^2N\mathfrak{f})^2$ such that $\chi(\mathfrak{p})\neq 1$. In particular, by taking $\mathfrak{f}$ the different of $K$, you get the result you want with a bound $27\log(\Delta_K)^2$.

Comment: Is there also any way to control the residue degree of the generating primes ? For example if we want all the generators to split completely. It seems to be easier to control the ramification since there are only finitely many ramified primes...

Comment: You can ask for only degree $1$ primes, the constant is multiplied by $6$. http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1990-55-191/S0025-5718-1990-1023756-8/

Comment: This is exactly what I need, merci beaucoup !

Comment: De rien, my pleasure ! :)

Comment: With $\mathfrak f$ the different of $K$, we consider the $\mathfrak f$-ray class field $K(\mathfrak f)$. How can we tell that $\mathfrak f$ is actually the conductor of $K(\mathfrak f)$ ? Don't we only have that the conductor divides $\mathfrak f$ ? It seems that if the conductor is strictly smaller than $\mathfrak f$, considering characters of the ray class field $K(\mathfrak f)$ doesn't allow us to get rid of the ramified primes in $K/\mathbb Q$. I guess I'm missing something...

Comment: Or maybe I'm simply confused with Bach's definition of a character. He says the characters on $K$ must be defined on the prime ideals as $\chi(\mathfrak p) = \phi\left(\frac{\mathfrak p}{L/K}\right)$ (Artin symbol + a homomorphism $\phi$ from $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ to the complex unit circle) if $\mathfrak p$ is unramified in $L/K$, and 0 otherwise, for some abelian extension $L/K$. If we consider the extension $K(\mathfrak f)/K$, and $\mathfrak p \mid \mathfrak f$ (ie. ramifies in $K/\mathbb Q$) but $\mathfrak p$ does not ramify in $K(\mathfrak f)/K$, characters will not be 0 at $\mathfrak p$.

Comment: In Bach's result, you do not have to assume that $\mathfrak{f}$ is the conductor of the character $\chi$, only that $\chi$ is defined modulo $\mathfrak{f}$.

Comment: Also see the "option 2" just before the theorem.

Comment: I agree that Bach's result doesn't require it to be the conductor, but then... Ok lets see how the proof would go. Let $S$ be a set of primes in $K$. Suppose it does not generate $\mathrm{Cl}_K$. Then it doesn't generate $\mathrm{Cl}_K(\mathfrak f)$, and there is a non trivial homomorphism $\phi : \mathrm{Cl}_K(\mathfrak f) \rightarrow \mathbb C^1$, which gives rise to $\chi$ such that $\chi(\mathfrak p) = \phi\left(\frac{\mathfrak p}{K(\mathfrak f)/K}\right)$ when $\mathfrak p$ is unramified in $K(\mathfrak f)/K$, 0 otherwise,

Comment: and $\chi $ is not principle. Then the theorem says that there is a $\mathfrak p$ of bounded norm, such that $\chi(\mathfrak p) \neq 0,1$. But $\mathfrak q \mid \mathfrak f$ doesn't imply that $\mathfrak q$ ramifies in $K(\mathfrak f)/K$ ($\mathfrak f$ is not necessarily the conductor), so "$\mathfrak q$ ramifies in $K/\mathbb Q$" does not imply $\chi(\mathfrak q) \neq 0,1$... So this $\mathfrak p$ given by the theorem could ramify in $K/\mathbb Q$... Where am I wrong ?

Comment: The theorem says that there is a $\mathfrak{p}$ **coprime to $\mathfrak{f}$** (otherwise $\chi(\mathfrak{p})$ does not even make sense!)  such that $\chi(\mathfrak{p})\neq 1$.

Comment: Ok, I feel a bit stupid... Talking about Theorem 4 of "explicit bounds for primality testing and related problems" ? I can't see the coprimality in the theorem... It seems to me that he uses the set of options in the lemmas, not in the theorem. And I don't see why $\chi(\mathfrak p)$ would not make sense : as long as $\mathfrak p$ is unramified in $K(\mathfrak f)/K$, the Artin symbol $\left(\frac{\mathfrak p}{K(\mathfrak f)/K}\right)$ is well defined and gives an element of $\mathrm{Gal}(K(\mathfrak f)/K)$. Using Bach's definition of a character.

Comment: The coprimality is implicit in the Theorem 4 (it is proved with Lemma 7.2). If you are not convinced, just use directly Lemma 7.2 to obtain what you need.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help ;) (and patience !)

Comment: No problem :) It is not your fault, maybe the paper would be clearer if he did not use CFT to define characters of the class groups and if he explicitly stated which primes he is considering in his Theorem 4.

Comment: Ok I have had a closer look (and helpful comments from Eric Bach) : the first bound (3) is with option 1 only, so we don't suppose $(\mathfrak p,\mathfrak f) = 1$. The second bound (12) is with option 1 and 2, i.e. we suppose $(\mathfrak p,\mathfrak f) = 1$. The last bound (18) is with option 1, 2 and 3, i.e. $(\mathfrak p,\mathfrak f) = 1$ and $\deg(\mathfrak p) = 1$.